# What is the correct term for an implementation of an interface that delegates method calls to a collection of the same interface?

Tags: java

I have an interface thus:

```
public interface Doer
{
    public void do(Object arg);
}
```

And I have an implementation that keeps a list of `Doers`, and does whatever on each:

```
public class DoerCollectionThing
    implements Doer
{
    private List<Doer> doers....

    public void addDoer(Doer d)
    {
        doers.add(d);
    }

    public void do(Object arg)
    {
        for (Doer d : doers){
            d.do(arg);
        }
    }
}
```

So, what do I call `DoerCollectionThing`? Is it a `DoerAggregator`? Or maybe `DoerCollectionDoer`? What do you all use for this type of thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct name for this is a `Composite`, because you're composing many implementations of an interface together into a single object.

Comment: So would you actually name `DoerCollectionThing` as `Composite`??

Comment: +1. Correct answer. For further reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern

Comment: Indeed, just saw that. Thanks GaryF!

Comment: I *think* I'd probably avoid this, because the term "composition" is somewhat overloaded these days. A design can use composition over inheritance, for example, without having anything like this situation. In other words, "composition" in general can be heterogeneous as well as homogeneous. I totally agree that it mirrors the Composite battern as back2dos referenced, but I just think it's a little too close to the general "composition" term. Just personal preference though :)

Answer (score 2):

I would call it a `MulticastDoer` or `BroadcastDoer`. Possibly `AggregatingDoer` although that may give the impression that it's performing aggregation of the *results*, which it doesn't in your example.

Answer (score 1):

In Effective Java 2nd Edition Item 16 this is called *Forwarding class*.

Comment: So, `DoerForwarder` perhaps then? :)

Comment: @aioobe: Bloch uses `ForwardingClass` names, like `ForwardingDoer`. But I'm not sure that it's applied for the case. Personally, I like Jon Skeet's version - `MulticastDoer`.

Comment: I'm not convinced. I think Bloch is talking about a 1 instance to 1 instance mapping of methods there. Here I am talking about 1 instance to many instance mapping.

Comment: I agree with @Jesse. A Forwarder tends to refer to basically a Delegate: 1-to-1 mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the correct answer to you question (as asked in the title) was given by Gary.

Concerning your other question, I'd have to say: pick a meaningfull name. If the "CollectionThing" only servers as a collection, that implements some interface `Foo`, then I suppose calling it `FooGroup` makes the most sense. It's neutral and self-explanatory.

But for example if you assume the following:

```
interface Drawable {
    void draw();
}
class Line implements Drawable {
    //methods to set start and end point as well as stroke thickness, color, etc.
    void draw() {
         //implementation here
    }
}
class LineGroup implements Drawable {
    //methods to add/remove lines
    void draw() {
         //call draw-method of all children
    }
}
```

This is also OK. But really `Path` would maybe make a better name than `LineGroup`. When I read a class name, I don't want to know, how it is implemented, i.e. delegation, composition, composite pattern or whatever. I want to know its purpose. Always use identifiers to convey purpose.

greetz
back2dos

Comment: Yep, but my "Composite"'s purpose IS to be a composite, so then maybe `CompositeDoer` is correct.

Comment: @Jesse: No, its purpose is not to be a composite. Its purpose is to group objects, to multicast/broadcast, or whatever. The use of the composite pattern is an implementation detail. You should know best, what the purpose of this class is, and should name it accordingly.